# UWP - C# / GraphicsCaptureItem How to choose My self

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to get a screen frame using UWP's GraphicCaptureItem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture#add-the-screen-capture-capability

I am referring to this sample.
The sample works fine.

But,

I don't want to use GraphicsCapturePicker(), I want to specify the current application directly.

Is there a way to assign itself (the application the code is running on) to the GraphicCaptureItem object?

Comment: [GraphicsCaptureItem.TryCreateFromWindowId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscaptureitem.trycreatefromwindowid?view=winrt-22621)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really appreciate you taking the time to share your thoughts. As of this time, however, there is no API in UWP that supports directly assigning application itself to the `GraphicCaptureItem` in screen capture. `GraphicsCaptureItem` class has no constructors, and the object of `GraphicsCaptureItem` can only be got from `GraphicsCaptureItem.CreateFromVisual(Visual)` method or `GraphicsCapturePicker.PickSingleItemAsync` method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Currently, I'm envisioning a video conferencing application that shares screens in real time.

Because the user has to deliver the screen of the conference application as it is
I don't want to use unnecessary Picker.

Are there any other alternatives?

Happy New Year.

Comment: Happy New Year. There is no better workaround for you to capture screen without using a picker in UWP. You could try to search for other traditional desktop project which can capture screen without using a picker, and then package the desktop app with the **Windows Application Packaging Project** to Universal Windows Platform. You could refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) or **Stefan**’s blog **UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 1** for more information about desktop bridge.